# error You seem to not be depending on @angular/core al ejecutar ng serve --open

Tags: angular

Porque me sale este error al ejecutar `ng serve --open`:

> C:\wamp64\www\my-app>ng serve --open You seem to not be depending on
>   "@angular/core". This is an error.

No entiendo talves hice algo mal al instalarlo? , yo se que esta bien porque al ejecutar `ng --version` me sale todo bien la versión del angular cli etc.

pero no me quiere ejecutar el `ng serve --open`

Comment: puedes agregar las versiones de node y npm  y tu package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas David! el error parece por falta de paquetes Angular. Prueba ejecutar en consola en tu directorio C:\wamp64\www\my-app con:

```
 npm install
```

Y luego prueba ejecutar nuevamente ng serve --open.

Saludos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71465/discussion-on-answer-by-lucas-accastello-error-al-ejecutar-ng-serve-open).

Answer (score 0):

- Borra node_modules y package-lock.json, de la carpeta "my-app".
  Donde esta tu proyecto (`C:\wamp64\www\my-app` - Abajo esta la estructura para que te orientes).
- Luego ejecute el siguiente comando, actualizará los paquetes npm.

  `npm install`

**Recomendaciones:**

Luego revisa el `package.json` y asegúrate de que exista la siguiente linea `"@angular/core": "5.0.4"` (la versión puede variar, tranquilo)

La estructura del proyecto auto generada debería ser así, para que te orientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra recomendación cuando instalas Angular, lo recomiendo hacer global por cualquier problema:

`npm install -g @angular/cli` // `-g` Hace referencia a una instalación global.

Comment: Comparto, pero el OP no conocía muy a fondo la estructura de su proyecto, prefería dejarle las respuesta (2 primeros items) y recomendaciones para que se oriente y no le vuelva a ocurrir.

Answer (score 0):

este error The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
es porque o te faltan paquetes de node en angular o no estas ejecutando en la ruta correcta el proyecto.
Se recomienda verificar que estas en la ruta correcta y si aún asi persiste el error es instalar en angularCli.